# Converting a datetime back to the original format

Tags: php, datetime, strtotime

I used this code

```
$new_date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', timetostr($orig_date));
```

to convert this input `Wed Jun 2 2010` to a `datetime` output `2010-06-02 00:00:00`

When I read it from the database, how do I convert it back to the original format of `Wed Jun 2 2010`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function `strftime()` (see [php.net manual: strftime()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strftime.php) for further information and all parameters) with specified parameters to convert the timestamp back to a human-readable format.

You can use the function this way `strftime("%a %b %d %Y")` where %a stands for the shortened name of the weekday, %b for the shortened name of the month, %d for the day of the month and %Y for the YYYY representation of the specified year.