# php strtotime reverse

Tags: php, strtotime

Is there some function `timetostr` in php that will output `today/tomorrow/next sunday/etc.` from a given timestamp? So that `timetostr(strtotime(x))=x`

Comment: date(). See http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: @Andypandy : I know about `date()`. I meant to ask, is there a direct function that will do reverse of `strtotime` ?

Comment: if not date, I don't know... could you provide some more context? something like this ($timestring = date('l', $timestamp) doesn't work?

Comment: I wrote one. Just added a switch-case over `($timestamp-strtodate('today'))/86400`. I was just wondering whether there already was a function builtin in php.

Comment: Check this out:

 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670161/how-to-create-a-friendly-date-format-for-example-submitted-2-days-ago

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This might be useful for people coming here.

```
/**
 * Format a timestamp to display its age (5 days ago, in 3 days, etc.).
 *
 * @param   int     $timestamp
 * @param   int     $now
 * @return  string
 */
function timetostr($timestamp, $now = null) {
    $age = ($now ?: time()) - $timestamp;
    $future = ($age < 0);
    $age = abs($age);

    $age = (int)($age / 60);        // minutes ago
    if ($age == 0) return $future ? "momentarily" : "just now";

    $scales = [
        ["minute", "minutes", 60],
        ["hour", "hours", 24],
        ["day", "days", 7],
        ["week", "weeks", 4.348214286],     // average with leap year every 4 years
        ["month", "months", 12],
        ["year", "years", 10],
        ["decade", "decades", 10],
        ["century", "centuries", 1000],
        ["millenium", "millenia", PHP_INT_MAX]
    ];

    foreach ($scales as list($singular, $plural, $factor)) {
        if ($age == 0)
            return $future
                ? "in less than 1 $singular"
                : "less than 1 $singular ago";
        if ($age == 1)
            return $future
                ? "in 1 $singular"
                : "1 $singular ago";
        if ($age < $factor)
            return $future
                ? "in $age $plural"
                : "$age $plural ago";
        $age = (int)($age / $factor);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an ERROR: unexpected 'list' (T_LIST). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Something todo with PHP versions? I got it working by declaring the list `list($singular, $plural, $factor) = $scale;` inside the foreach and replacing the list in the foreach prams with `$list`

Comment: That's correct.  PHP 5.5 added "Unpacking nested arrays with list()" (http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Thank you! That saved me a lot of time. This should be a built in function!

Answer (score 2):

There cannot be a `strtotime` reverse function because this is not a bijection. The source string from which you get a UNIX timestamp when you use `strtotime`can be formatted in many different ways. So if you decide to reverse the function, how can you know what string format to use ? It could well be 2010-08-05 or 10 September 2000, etc. This is exactly why there is no reverse function, but as Andypandy rightly said, you have to use `date()`which allows you to actually define the string format you wish to end up with. I know this question is old, but I thought it deserved this answer so other users understand why there is no such function in PHP.

Comment: whilst technically "correct" this does not answers the OP's question, rather it just furthers a negative stereotype of the all knowing programmer who knows better than the person asking the question. another approach would be to say something like this--> http://stackoverflow.com/a/3040437/830899

Comment: date("Y-m-d",time()) can do the job.